# How can I run VBA code only once? How to disable VBA after operation is complete?

Tags: excel, vba

Users fill out a "MAIN" form. At this point, no other sheet is visible by default.
Users click submit, the "Main sheet" is meant to disappear forever, and the "filled out sheet" appears which will be the ongoing sheet for the life of the project.

For specific reasons, and issues of porting data from MAIN sheet (single cells) to the hidden sheet (merged cells), my workaround copies and pastes data to get rid of the formulas once the user hits submit, so they can work with a clean form without possibly messing up the chaos of merged cells and formulas.

After saving and re-opening, the VBA resets. **How can I keep the "MAIN" form hidden after they perform this operation, and never run this VBA again?**

```vb
Sub PopupBox()

    Dim answer As Integer

    answer = MsgBox("Are you sure you are ready to prepare the RFQ form? Action cannot be undone!", vbOKCancel)

    If answer = vbOK Then

        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("RFQ FORM INT").Activate
        Worksheets("RFQ FORM INT").Visible = True

        Dim wbSource As Workbook
        Dim wbDest As Workbook
        Dim wsSource As Worksheet
        Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    
        Set wbSource = ThisWorkbook
        Set wsSource = wbSource.Sheets("RFQ FORM INT")
    
        Set wbDest = ThisWorkbook
        Set wsDest = wbDest.Sheets("RFQ FORM INT")
    
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        'Copy values and formats of range B15:M54
        wsSource.Range("B15:M54").Copy
        wsDest.Range("B15").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
        'Copy values and formats of range B2:F4
        wsSource.Range("B2:F4").Copy
        wsDest.Range("B2:F4").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
    
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("MAIN").Activate
        Worksheets("MAIN").Visible = False
    
        'Change below item to True while working / editing this document.
    Else
        Worksheets("RFQ FORM INT").Visible = False
    End If
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not just create a new workbook from the file you're in? Copy/transform sheets you need and save it as a different file. Or if the button is triggering the code, just delete/hide the sheet with the button or delete the button (iirc this is possible). If it's from the Workbook_Open event, you could also have a hidden sheet where you read if a cell has a certain value there and at the end of your code set it to that value.

Comment: You might also use the [Worksheet.Visible](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.visible) property. At the beginning of your code you check for its status and if the sheet is not visible you exit the code.

Comment: Thanks everyone. Good feedback. I will probably attempt to change a cell value after this code. So a cell will start out with "1" and I can use something like  If Target.Cells.Count < 1 Then Exit Sub, then after clicking button, force change that cell to "2" for example. I think this will solve it, but gotta test it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly You mean a UserForm or a Worksheet under "MAIN" form.
But if permanently want to disable your code the easiest way is to delete the button which starts the VBA code.